# Changing my statement to work in a SQL function

Tags: sql

I wanted to create a view using my SQL statement but found out you can't use `declare` in a view. So I was trying to create a function so my view could just call it

This is the SQL statement

```
--Declare necessary variables
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE   @Pivot AS NVARCHAR(255)

--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT @Pivot = COALESCE(@Pivot + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Stage)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Stage 
     FROM [dbo].[F_Work_Order_Summary]) AS Pivot

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT * 
                  FROM [dbo].[F_Work_Order_Summary] 
                  PIVOT(SUM(Time_In_Stage) 
                        FOR Stage IN (' + @Pivot + ')) AS P'

--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Was wonder if anyone could help or knows a better way to use this statement with a view.

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is SQL-Server? **It is not possible!** Using dynamically created statements cannot work in *ad-hoc* queries like VIEWs or (inline) functions. The (really bad!) multi-statement-function  will not allow this as well. So the only chance is a stored procedure...

Comment: did you try with a table-valued user function ?

Comment: how would you like to use this function?

Comment: I just want to be able to run a select * from this table.